# Dateadded in OSX using c++

Tags: c, c++17

How do I get "date added" in OSX using C++?
Finder in OSX provides "date added" attribute for files.
Neither by looking at `filesystem` library in C++17 any result can be reached nor by using the `stat` struct in `sys/stat.h`.
Where this should be looked for?

Answer (score 0):

This information is part of "extended attributes" of Mac OS. See [extended attributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileprovideritemprotocol/3074511-extendedattributes).

You need to find a C++ library for it or call the C API [`getxattr()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getxattr.2.html).